# Merge Sort IndexError

Tags: python, mergesort, index-error

This is my first merge sort implementation with Python.

```
unsorted_list = [7, 4, 2, 1]


def merge(left_array, right_array):
    lst = []

    # Compare the element in both arrays
    i = 0
    while len(left_array) > 0 and len(right_array) > 0:
        if left_array[i] <= right_array[i]:
            lst.append(left_array[i])
            del left_array[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            lst.append(right_array[i])
            del right_array[i]
            i += 1

    # Append the rest if one of the array is empty
    if len(left_array) > 0:
        for j in left_array:
            lst.append(j)

    if len(right_array) > 0:
        for h in right_array:
            lst.append(h)

    # Return the sorted sub-list
    return lst


def merge_sort(array):
    # Return the array if there is only one element
    if len(array) <= 1:
        return array

    # Divide the array in two halves
    mid = (len(array))//2
    left = array[:mid]
    right = array[mid:]

    # Recursion
    merge_sort(right)
    merge_sort(left)
    return merge(left, right)


print(merge_sort(unsorted_list))
```

But the console showed this error instead of a sorted list:

```
 File "c:\Users\...\merge_sort.py", line 64, in <module>
    print(merge_sort(unsorted_list))
  File "c:\Users\...\merge_sort.py", line 62, in merge_sort
    return merge(left, right)
  File "c:\Users\...\merge_sort.py", line 28, in merge
    if left_array[i] <= right_array[i]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I expect the result should be this or something like that:

```
[1, 2, 4, 7]
```

As *i* goes from 0 and it stops adding if one array, i.e., *right_array* and *left_array* goes empty, *i* should not be greater than the largest index of the array.

I don’t know how to solve my error. How can I correct it?

Comment: there are error when i = 1, left_array = [7,4], lst =[2], right_array = [1]

Comment: Iterate through `left` and `right` **or** consume their elements (removing them).  ***Choose one***.

Comment: Don't forget that for the list [7, 4, 2, 1] the lowest index is -4 and the highest is 3. Also, a typical mergesort implementation should not need to remove items from any list(s)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the two lines where *i+=1*. And replace *i* with 0.

In your current code, while you delete *num* from list, you increment *i* by 1. Then actually miss some numbers in both the left and right arrays.

Example: in a list (variable name as *arr*) have two numbers as follows [1,2]. If you delete one then the new list is [2]. When you call arr[1], now it returns indexError, because now there is no two nums in the list.